# NextJS 13.4 can't build statically for S3 deployment with Cloud Front & Cloud Front function

Tags: next.js, deployment, static, aws-cdk, next.js13

I am writing the deployment code for deploying our NextJS 13.4 App, using the src/app folder.

We have Supabase Authentification that uses cookies for saving the auth token, etc...

We have client component inside server component (not wrapped in Suspense). Accessing cookies in Server component layout in order to redirect at the root, if some one isn't logged in for instance.

Now to deploy to AWS, we are trying to do it with a S3 Bucket, CloudFront and CloudFront function fro serving dynamic pages.

However I need to export the next app, overall, statically, so it can get deployed to S3, then the Cloud Front function will take care of the dynamic requests. I am blocked on that one, as NextApp 13.4+ but the next build script generated an out folder.
I do get a folder /.next, and 5 folders in it /cache, /export, /server, /static, /types, and a bunch of random json files

the export folder contains a 404.html, 500.html, and a /_next weird name.

I am unsure on where this is going wrong, but I would have expected an index.html that can be used by Cloud Front.

I wonder if NextJS 13 is just too new and still a few bugs and things missing ?All I have tried it above.

I try to actually create an Amplify app, just in case I was doing something wrong...but even that doesn't actually server a valid next app, I just get a 500 for my routes.

I can deploy S3, Cloud Front & the Cloud Front function, but it doesn't work either, I don't get a page.

I know we could try to use netlify or vercel servers, but we already have our backend in AWS, and a bunch of AWS Services related to it, so we want to keep every thing under one roof if possible.

Thanks.